# AngularJS: Get interpolated attribute values in directive when init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have directive in AngularJS 1.0.8 called custom-check-box-enquire. The directive is in a list of filters. When the user clicks on a filter the directive should change the style. This is working fine inside the changeIconCheck function. However, the filter is initialise with some filters already selected, so those filters should be highlighted. I´m trying to highlight those filters in the init method checking if the attribute id is included in the filters list. However, when angular evaluates the directive and execute the init method for first time, the id attribute is still undefined. Please, see the sample code.

```js
.directive('customCheckBoxEnquire', function() {

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {

    function init() {
      var selectedStates = scope.filter.states;
      console.log("States=" + selectedStates);
      var index = selectedStates.indexOf(parseInt(attrs.id));
      if (index != -1) {
        element.addClass('selected');
        var checkElement = element.children('.fa-icon-check-empty');
        checkElement.removeClass('fa-icon-check-empty').addClass('fa-icon-check');
      }
    }

    function changeIconCheck() {
      init();
      element.click(function() {
        if (element.hasClass('selected')) {
          element.removeClass('selected');
          var checkElement = element.children('.fa-icon-check');
          checkElement.removeClass('fa-icon-check').addClass('fa-icon-check-empty');
        } else {
          element.addClass('selected');
          var checkElement = element.children('.fa-icon-check-empty');
          checkElement.removeClass('fa-icon-check-empty').addClass('fa-icon-check');
        }
      });
    }
    changeIconCheck();
  }

  return {
    link: link
  };
})
```

```html
<li id="{{state.id}}" ng-repeat="state in enquireStates" class="cursor-pointer"
    ng-click="onFilterState(state.id)" custom-check-box-enquire>
  <i class="fa-icon-check-empty"></i> 
  {{state.name | translate}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it. I observed the attribute.

```
attrs.$observe('id', function(val) {#do whatever});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Directive Attributes API Reference - $observe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe)